# Missing activity data after updating to iOS14

Tags: iphone, ios

I updated my iPhone to iOS14 last night, and updated my watch to watchOS7.

This morning I noticed that all of my activity data for Tuesday is gone! Nothing at all - no exercise, no stands - nothing.

I was at work all day that day and closed all of my rings and more.

The craziest thing is that at the bottom of the screen, it still shows that I earned a "200%" on my red ring -  but says I did no exercise, no stands, burned no calories?!

Any suggestions? I have restarted both my watch and my phone, with no change.

Hoping this is just some weird glitch and it will come back again over the next couple of days?!

[image]

Comment: It might still be syncing between your Watch and iPhone.  I saw similar issues during the beta period.  I *think* they were resolved simply by waiting.  Make sure bluetooth is on for both devices and they stay connected via wifi.

Comment: I once had to go for a second run at 11:24 pm to get my rings closed after an upgrade tool most of the day. I now get my rings done, back up my phone before I will upgrade. Have you called Apple Support to be sure they can push or confirm the data is safe?

Comment: UPDATE: I get up this morning and all of Tuesday's data is showing now, but all of Wednesday's data is blank?!?! So all the data must be there somewhere!